# python return value of a function in a function that includes a function?

Tags: python, function, return

I have a question, is it possible to return a value of a function in a function that includes a function?
That's what I mean:

```
def function(flag=1):
    signal_0 = 1
    if flag==0:
        signal_1 = input("0 or 1?")
    select = 0
    output = (not select and signal_0) or (select and signal_1)
    return output, select

def connection(func): 
    eingang = func()[0]
    return eingang 

f.exp. like that: 

def final(func): 
    eingang = func()
    a = eingang + 1 
    return a 

print(function(0))
print(connection(function))
print(final(connection)) ????
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible.

Comment: I think you want `print(final(connection(function)))` on the last line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

Yes, it is possible if you run a function in other function and then get the returned value. I am using this method here. You can also use decorators for the purpose.

=======

```
def function(flag=1):
    signal_0 = 1
    if flag==0:
        signal_1 = input("0 or 1?")
    select = 0
    output = (not select and signal_0) or (select and signal_1)
    return output, select

def connection(func): 
    eingang = func[0]
    return eingang 

# f.exp. like that: 

def final(func): 
    eingang = func
    a = eingang + 1 
    return a 

func=function(0)
connec=connection(func)
final_function=final(connec)

print(final_function)
```